# truncate float values to 8 decimal places with pandas.to_excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, floating-point, precision

I have a data frame with columns containing float values. 
One of the cells contain a value of **0.021893287**

I have set the pandas option to:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 8)
```

When I try to export the data frame to excel :

```
data_final.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',float_format='%.8f',index=False)
```

When I see the value in excel, it shows me a value **0.02189329**

However I want a value of **0.02189328**

Comment: Why would you want a value that is incorrect?

Comment: @IanS I jst want 8 digits after my decimal point. It is round of the value to make '29' at the end because it is rounding of 0.021893287 to 0.02189329. I don't want to round off.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a string, truncate it, then convert it back to float. For example:

`float(str(0.021893287)[0:10])` will output `0.02189328`

In the DataFrame `data_final`, you could do this to the whole column

```
data_final['col_name'].apply(lambda x: float(str(x)[0:10])
```